# Get distance between two points based on two columns of one oracle sql table

Tags: sql, oracle, distance

I am trying to calculate distance in metres between two points by using the long and lat of every point. The data are all in on table with the below format

Table1

```
Place_Nm  Land_name LONG_pl     LONG_ln     LAT_pl      LAT_ln    
Place1    Land031   61.43305    71.43611    35.25326    85.3654
Place2    Land032   91.44204    21.43611    95.32857    85.3054
Place3    Land033   61.49735    71.43611    35.67956    95.3654
Place4    Land034   11.50326    81.43611    15.35913    65.6054
```

I want to add another column which will be the distance between value of place_nm column and land_name column

I have tried using the below code but I get error messages

```
SELECT a.*, sdo_geom.sdo_distance(sdo_geom.sdo_geometry(2001, 8307, sdo_geom.sdo_point_type(long_pl, lat_pl, NULL), NULL, NULL),
                           sdo_geom.sdo_geometry(2001, 8307, sdo_point_type(long_ln, lat_ln, NULL), NULL, NULL), 0.0001, 'unit=M') distance_in_m
                           from table1 a;
```

The error message that I get is

ORA-13032: Invalid NULL  SDO_GEOMETRY object
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_3GL", line 2089
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_GEOM", line 2096

I also tried to use the below query but it seems to bring back results that seem to be very low for a distance in metres or too high for a distance in kms.

```
SELECT ((ACOS(SIN(lat_pl * 3.141592653 / 180) * SIN(lat_ln * 3.141592653 / 180) + 
COS(lat_pl * 3.141592653 / 180) * COS(lat_ln * 3.141592653 / 180) * COS((long_pl - long_ln) * 3.141592653 / 180)) * 180 / 3.141592653) 
* 60 * 1.8531) AS distance  
FROM table1;
```

Thanks

Comment: Your query runs for given examples, here is the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9c3e5d23ac3f3bb7296de6b20fdaad4e). Maybe you have some null values in your table?

Comment: You are actually right! If I remove the null long and lat values, the query works. And it brings almost the same result as the other query I used. Thanks a lot!